# How to make all *.mysite.com subdomains to hit my servlet

Tags: servlets, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

We have a web application, say mysite.com.

Now users can come and create pages like, mysite.com/page/mypage. Here 'mypage' is unique identifier for the page he/she has created. So whenever mysite.com/page/mypage url is requested, it hits our 'pagerequestservlet', which gives out requested page data.

Now what I want is, whenever user hits, mypage.mysite.com, then also we give out the same page related info (that we give out on mysite.com/page/mypage). This would mean, I need to make all my *.mysite.com requests to be handled by 'pagerequestservlet' (or a similar servlet). Then I can just parse the request URL, identify the identifier 'mypage' and return the data.

Now my question is, how to make all my *.mysite.com requests to be handled by 'pagerequestservlet'? I am using GoDaddy as my domain registrar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must setup your DNS to allow such wildcards, I don't know wheter GoDaddy supports this.

A servlet is "DNS-agnostic", normally it does not need to know anything about its domain name. This way it's possible to deploy the same servlet on different environments or even with different context roots (example.com/a and example.com/b).

You still have access to the domain name via [ServletRequest#getServerName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerName%28%29). You could implement a Filter that handles the subdomain part and redirect to the correct page. But be aware - if you run in a clustered environment or behind a load balancer, this would **not** return mypage.example.com, but the name of the host ther servlet was deployed to.